# Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find info.magnolia:magnolia-project:pom:4.5.12

Tags: maven, magnolia

This is my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
<artifactId>magnolia-blossom-samples</artifactId>
<groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
<version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
<groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
<artifactId>magnolia-blossom-sample-module</artifactId>
 <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>magnolia-blossom-sample-module</name>
 <properties>
 <magnoliaVersion>4.5.12</magnoliaVersion>
<javaVersion>1.6</javaVersion>
<springVersion>3.1.4.RELEASE</springVersion>
</properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
  <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-rendering</artifactId>
  <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-templating</artifactId>
  <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-templating-jsp</artifactId>
  <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-module-fckeditor</artifactId>
  <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-module-blossom</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${springVersion}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>${springVersion}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- For @Valid - JSR-303 Bean Validation API -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- TEST -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${javaVersion}</source>
      <target>${javaVersion}</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

  <!-- default resources configuration which will filter the module descriptor -->
  <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>META-INF/magnolia/*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
 </resources>
 </build>

 <repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>magnolia.public</id>
  <url>http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public</url>
  <snapshots>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
 <!-- IF YOU NEED MODULES FROM THE ENTERPRISE VERSION, UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING REPOSITORY -->
<!--
<repository>
  <id>magnolia.enterprise.releases</id>
     <url>http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/repositories/magnolia.enterprise.releases</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
   </repository>
-->
 </repositories>

 </project>
```

I am facing the above exception. at the `<?xml version ....`

and error showing in `<dependency>` also.

Is there any code is missing or any wrong expression is present in this pom.xml file.

How to resolved this error please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Without sharing what exact errors you are getting it's hard to guess. But I would think you have wrong url to nexus, it's available only over https so try to change all `http://nexus.mangolia-cms.com` to `https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com` and see if maven can resolve dependencies then. If not please post the error you are getting too.

HTH,
Jan